# How to Create SOAP POST Request using AFNetworking 3.0 and OC

Tags: ios

This is my first time to make a SOAP Request using AFNetworking 3.0 I don't know how to do.Using SOAP UI, this is the Request Format.

```
POST /LoginAndRegiste.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: 58.215.179.167
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <MyLogin xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <uName>string</uName>
      <pwd>string</pwd>
    </MyLogin>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
```